# Sencha Touch 2 image and video gallery with index bar

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm working on a Sencha touch2 app. I need to implement a gallery for images and videos with index bar.
If anyone know about some library or opensource project, please let me know.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy and simple steps for making a Sencha Touch image gallery: http://innofied.com/mosaic-image-gallery-with-sencha-touch-2-2/
Here you can find [demo](http://apps.innofied.com/iphonetest/?url=http://apps.innofied.com/blog/senchagallery) as well as the [source](https://github.com/innofied/senchagallery). Follow this, it will surely help you.